# TwinCAT Is there a difference when building a project in release or debug mode?

Tags: twincat

I've always wondered if there is a difference if you build a PLC project in the *Debug* or *Release* configuration. I don't think there is since the `.compileinfo` file in the  `_CompileInfo` folder is the same size and it has the same filename (some hash I guess). Also when I log in after building with the other configuration, I do not get the prompt if I want to log in with online changes.

Does anyone know if the build configuration has an influence on the compiled code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

No, there is no change to the built code.

---

Long Answer:

The *Build Configuration* Tools that are referred to are primarily designed for implementation with general text based languages, rather than the TwinCAT layer that Beckhoff has stacked on top of Visual Studio.
Under standard languages there are a lot of properties that can be managed at the project level, and these properties are what are being modified when you change from *debug* to *release* [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-project-and-solution-properties?view=vs-2019).

Twincat projects however are made up of two separate projects (proj_a.tsproj, proj_a.plcproj), and Visual Studio only recognizes one of these as a project file that can be modified, the *.tsproj*.
So if you want to see what properties will be modified by swapping between *debug* and *release*, have a look at what properties are available from the .tsproj file.

If you want to test this yourself you can disable a project file (proj_a.tsproj) and swap between debug/release to see the disabled status change as a result of swapping between the two build configurations.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the reply. I didn't mean the Released check in the common settings of the project properties. I meant the build configuration which can be set in Visual Studio in the menu *Build > Configuration Manager*.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense about your confusion. Will update my response to make my understanding of that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example. I tried it and indeed it changes the disabled status! Not sure who down voted you, but I guess it was because of the old answer? It would have been nice to leave a comment, instead of (just) a down vote.